# How to show documents that doesn't have an specific key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to obtain all the documents in a collection that doesn't have an specific key called "_content_Type".

I was attempting to compare with null or "" but it doesn't work.

```
db.fs.files.find({"_contentType":""}).count()

0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [$exists](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator:
`{ _contentType: { $exists: false } }`